# JPanel Gridlayout column doesn't work

Tags: swing

I tried to divide my JPanel into 4 boxes

```
---------
|   |   |
---------
|   |   |
---------
```

So I have

```
pluginPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2, 10, 10));
```

But no matter How I changed the col

```
pluginPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, x, 10, 10));
```

It just give me the same thing

```
------
|    |
------
|    |
------
```

Im putting my pluginPanel into another panel. and the outerpanel will be put in the JFrame.

Is there any reasons for this?

Comment: An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) would be useful. That's not how `GridLayout` is supposed to work so it must be due to something else in how you create the window contents and layout.

Comment: Seems to me like you are only adding two components to the panel.